# Troubles in refreshing table data after an update (block/Unblock)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I having troubles when I click update button block/Unblock status of Comments  User, after calling function (query update). Using ajax it returns 
"success" and nothing should happens. If I manually refresh the page than updated information is shown. I want to show my updated record in a table after returning ajax response "success". Please suggest me.

`enter code here`

```
          $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".blockUser").click(function(e){ 

                if(confirm("Are sure want to Block this User")){

                    var msg=prompt("Please Enter your message");
                    var txt= $.trim( msg );
                    if(txt){
                        blockUser=this.id;
                        var loginUserId=document.getElementById('loginUserId').value;
                        var info='blockUser=' +blockUser;
                        $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajaxCall.php",
                            data:{loginUserId: loginUserId,blockUser: blockUser,message: msg},
                            success:function(data)
                            {
                                localtion.reload(0);
                                alert("User block successfully"); 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            $(".UnblockUser").click(function(e)
            { 
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to UnBlock User")) {
                    UnblockUser=this.id;
                    var loginUserId=document.getElementById('loginUserId').value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajaxCall.php",
                        data: {loginUserId: loginUserId,UnblockUser: UnblockUser},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            localtion.reload(0);
                            alert("User UnBlock successfully");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please post the javascript code you are currently using, and the code in the PHP file that ajax is calling.

Comment: Here is my JavaScript code please review..

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".blockUser").click(function(e){ 

            var text = $(e.target).text();
            if(text == 'Block'){
                if(confirm("Are sure want to Block this User")){

                    var msg=prompt("Please Enter your message");
                    var txt= $.trim( msg );
                    if(txt){
                        blockUser=this.id;
                        var loginUserId=document.getElementById('loginUserId').value;
                        var info='blockUser=' +blockUser;
                        $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajaxCall.php",
                            data:{loginUserId: loginUserId,blockUser: blockUser,message: msg},
                            success:function(data)
                            {
                                 $("#"+blockUser).text("Unblock");
                                $("#"+blockUser).removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger");
                                //localtion.reload(0);
                                //$("#blockrow"+blockUser+"").replaceWith(data);
                                alert("User block successfully"); 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            if(text == 'UnBlock'){
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to UnBlock User")) {
                    UnblockUser=this.id;
                    alert(UnblockUser);
                    var loginUserId=document.getElementById('loginUserId').value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajaxCall.php",
                        data: {loginUserId: loginUserId,UnblockUser: UnblockUser},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                        //localtion.reload(0);
                        alert("User UnBlock successfully");
                        $("#"+UnblockUser).text("Block");
                        $("#"+UnblockUser).removeClass("btn-danger").addClass(" btn-success");
                       // $("#blockrow"+UnblockUser+"").replaceWith(data);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            });
        });
```